# Anchor tag CSS hover color logic

Tags: html, css

I'm confused by the logic that CSS is using to determine what color to use for an anchor tag during a hover event.  In case it's relevant, I am using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit) on Mac OS X 10.10.3.

If I declare a global style rule for an `a` tag and a global style rule for `a:hover`, it seems that in some cases the color chosen for the `a` tag will also be used to override the hover color, but other times the hover color will be taken from the global `a:hover` rule.  I know that is confusing, so here's the code:

**CSS**

```
a {
    color:blue;
}

a:hover {
    color:red;
}

#container a {
    color: orange;
}

#container2 a {
    color:green;
}

footer a {
     color: pink;   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">Body Link: Color changes on hover</a>

<div id="container">
    <a href="#">#Container Link: Color does not change on hover</a>
</div>

<div id="container2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">#Container2 Link: Color does not change on hover</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<footer>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Footer Link: Color changes on hover</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Here's a fiddle with the working code:  http://jsfiddle.net/flyingL123/cLunqpbx/

Why does the color change on hover for only some of the links?

Comment: See this article on specificity. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: You can use your browser's built in code inspector to see what style rules apply to a tag, and in what order - which determines what rules override each other.

Comment: See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) and [this](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Answer (score 0):

This question is about CSS priority level.

In your demo, if you want to color change on hover for all the links, use !important;

```
a:hover {
    color:red!important;
}
```

new demo http://jsfiddle.net/cLunqpbx/7/